# JQuery alternate div content and AJAX post url on each click

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some JQuery handling a div click. If the div is clicked once it hides itself and shows another div (and posts to a php script in the background). If it is then clicked again, it's supposed to hide the new div, show the new one again, and post more data to a different script, and so on.

It changes the first time (.f hides, .uf shows) but when I click '.uf' nothing happens.

JQuery:

```
if($('.f').is(":visible")) {
    $('#follow').click(function() {
        var to_follow = $('.name').attr('id');
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/bin/rel_p.php",  
            data: "y=" + to_follow,  
            success: function() {  
                $('.f').hide();
                $('.uf').show();
            }
        });
    });
}
else {
    $('#follow').click(function() {
        var to_unfollow = $('.name').attr('id');
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/bin/relu_p.php",  
            data: "y=" + to_follow,  
            success: function() {  
                $('.uf').hide();
                $('.f').show();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
            <div id="follow" class="f">
                <img src="img/icons/Follow.png">
                <h1>Follow</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="follow" class="uf" style="display:none;">
                <img src="img/icons/Unfollow.png">
                <h1>Unfollow</h1>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you binding this to a click, inside an if/else statement, and is this inside another click function or some other strangeness?

Comment: "$('#follow').click(function() {...});"

Comment: Oboy, and that's suppose to work when the if statement is outside the click function ?

Comment: Now I feel stupid :') I see what you mean, I'll give that a go

Comment: To start off, both your div's have id='follow'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a class if you intend to use the selector twice, and don't write the same code twice unless you have to:

```
$('.follow').on('click', function() {
    var is_f = $('.f').is(":visible"),
        to_follow = $('.name').attr('id'),
        give_me_an_u = is_f?'':'u';
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/bin/rel" + give_me_an_u + "_p.php",  
        data: {y : to_follow}
    }).done(function() {
        $('.f, .uf').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I get it, but I get nothing when I click the div, classes now read <div id="follow" class="follow f"> and <div id="follow" class="follow uf">

Comment: You should only use an ID once, that's why I used a class, but that won't help much if you keep the same ID on the elements ?